# Temporary conversation ending doubt

Tags: java, jsf, seam, seam-conversation

I've been working with Seam recently and temporary conversations still confuse me.

In our project we're using `ExternalContext.redirect()` to redirect the user to the response page. From what I've read, a Seam conversation ends when the render response phase is called.

But then I read somewhere else that: *[Seam transparently propagates the conversation context (including the temporary conversation context) across JSF postbacks and redirects](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2/reference/en-US/html/conversations.html)*.

So what happens when I redirect to the same page is that commandLinks have the same conversationId appended to its action url always. I've tried to end the temp conversation with  `<f:param name="conversationPropagation" value="none"/>`, as the page says, but that causes that when the redirected page is rendered, the conversation context is already fred and a bean we where using can't be no longer used in the response.

So what I want to know, is that if there's a way to end the conversation with a redirect and mantain the context until the rendering of the response?

If not, when does a temp conversation really end? Because since the conversation context is propagated through redirects and postbacks, then it seams to me it will never end.

Answer (score 0):

I thing CONVERSATION scope is automatic maintain by a SEAM Frame work throw UI if you want to create a new conversation then you can do like this.

```
<h:commandButton id="conId" value="New Conversation" 
    action="#{conversationManager.clearConversation('/views/Hello.seam')}">  
</h:commandButton>
```

i am not sure but if you want to close a CONVERSATION then you can try like this.

```
getConversation().end();
```

i am not sure it will work or not.